# how to write LINQ to objects equivalent code for this code

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How can we write LINQ equivalent code of this code:

```
foreach (Function objFunc in _objCFLFile.CFLFunctionsList)
{
     if (objFunc.Name == txtFunctionName.Text)
     {
          ShowMessage(Constants.M10036);
          return false;
     }
}
```

thanks guys i marked your answers as +1
If i wish to add one more condition like this

```
foreach (Function objFunc in _objCFLFile.CFLFunctionsList)
            {
                if (objFunc.Name == txtFunctionName.Text && objFunc.Signature == OtherFunction.Signature)
                {
                    ShowMessage(Constants.M10046);//function already exists
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

in this case also there are various LINQ syntax but which will b the perfect one , efficient one ?

Comment: All the answers are equivalent, except for Aliostad's. You can add the extra condition simply by adding the && etc. To the lambda expression passed to Any()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (_objCFLFile.CFLFunctionsList.Any(f => f.Name == txtFunctionName.Text))
{
  ShowMessage(Constants.M10036);
  return false;
}
```

With your extra requirement:

```
if (_objCFLFile.CFLFunctionsList.Any(f => f.Name == txtFunctionName.Text &&
                                     f.Signature == OtherFunction.Signature))
{
  ShowMessage(Constants.M10036);
  return false;
}
```

If you have many more conditions to add it might be worth creating a method to do the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

```
if (_objCFLFile.CFLFunctionsList.Any(objFunc => 
                  objFunc.Name == txtFunctionName.Text))            
            {
                ShowMessage(Constants.M10036);                     
                return false; 
            }
```